# Cauchy Integralformula comprehension question

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, holomorph

So, I saw the following step in a lecture$  \int_{|z|=3}^{} \frac{e^{-z}}{(z+2)^3}dz=\frac{2 \pi i}{2}e^2 \ $ with the cauchy integralformula where |z|=3 is the circle around 0 with radius 3. Now my question, doesn't the formula require the function to be holomorphic on the circle and on the entire set enclosed by the circle? If so, shouldn't the formula not be applicable here since there is a singularity inside the circle at -2? Or is there an implicit step here that circumvents the singularity?

Comment: You can also get this result with the residue theorem. Nonetheless, we only need to ensure the path encloses the singularity.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I just realized I was a bit too hasty in asking this question. I misremembered the integralformula and thought the holomorphic condition is required of the entire term in the integral. Thanks nontheless.

Answer (score 1):

It is the generalized Cauchy integral formula:

$$f^{(n)}(w) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma} \frac{f(\xi)}{(\xi-w)^{n+1}} d\xi$$

for the holomorphic function $f(z) = e^{-z}$, $\Gamma$ the circle $|z|=3$, and $n=2$.

Now, for your question

> Now my question, doesn't the formula require the function to be holomorphic on the circle and on the entire set enclosed by the circle?

the answer is **Yes and something more**. More precisely, if $f:D \subseteq \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $\Gamma \subseteq D$ is the image of a closed simple curve and $K$ is the interior of $\Gamma$, then in order to use the (generalized) Cauchy integral formula one has to verify that there exists some open set $U\subseteq D$ on which $f$ is holomorphic such that $\overline{K} \subseteq U$.